# How do I use Sonar Plugin with Hudson?

Tags: sonarqube, hudson, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want to use SonarQube for Code Quality analysis. I have Hudson as the CI tool and have integrated clearcase. How do I use SonarQube when the Ant build happens? Do I need to install SonarQube in a server and use a plugin to access it? 
Can someone help  me?

Comment: I recommend to start reading the documentation. https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/home.html

Answer (score 1):

Install [SonarQube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) web server as a first step. Default port will be localhost:9000.

After installing SonarQube you need to create an [Ant target](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Analyzing+with+Ant+SonarQube+Task). Sample Script is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples/tree/master/sonarqube-scanner-ant). If Hudson is working correctly earlier. It will pick up the changes in Ant Script and perform the Analysis. After the completion of Analysis report will be generated and accessible at SonarQube Web Dashboard.